# error in SQLite query building

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my code I try to pull data from database , but `SELECTARGS` is not properly fit with data type of QUERY... I have done like this:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
String selectSQL = "Select * from " + Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME
                + " where " + Wish_list_Table.COL_CATEGORY + "";
String[] SelectionArgs = new String[1];
SelectionArgs[0] = al.get(1);
String[] add = { "" + SelectionArgs[0] };
Log.i("select_string", "" + add.toString());

TextView textView = getGenericView();
Cursor selectdata = db.rawQuery(selectSQL, add);
```

Comment: log cat...java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You prepared the add parameter for your query, but didn't pass it:
you're missing **= ?** in your query...

```
String selectSQL = "Select * from " + Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME +
    " where " + Wish_list_Table.COL_CATEGORY + " = ?";
```

Now, what to do with that...

Once you have your cursor filled (don't follow this query, it's vey specific to
my app):

```
    final Cursor cur = db.rawQuery
        (
            "SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y', [date]) Year FROM " +
                DB_TABLE + " WHERE Year > date('now', '-11 years') " +
                "ORDER BY Year DESC", null
        );
```

You can extract the column values very easily:

```
    if (cur != null)
    {
        if (cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            tmp = new String[cur.getCount()];
            do
            {
                tmp[cur.getPosition()] =
                    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Year"));
            }
            while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cur.close();
```

tmp is a String[] I previously defined and need filled by this method, which returns a string array (an array of years in form of strings) basing on a number (a year)

What's notable is:

```
1 - check wether the Cursor is null. If so, just return something empty or null.
2 - If (hopefully) not, move to the first record and cycle till the end of the records, taking the value/s from the column/s you're interested in (normally you'd only select the columns you're interested in, because * is an overkill)
```

If you only return **1 row, it's even easier**:
just move to the first record and extract each column from your row (not cycling).

And (just for completeness and not to induce you to use rawQuery for SQL commands), you can INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE by using the **execSQL** function (this one is **not a SQL query**, but a **SQL command**, since you modify the db).

Comment: i updated with that and showing this error....java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: thanks..bro..i got solution ..there was missing space between.

Comment: Do you mean how to extract the column value from the cursor?

Comment: i mean by using Where key in query ,will get specific row of the column,but i need all the row of that column ..by using rawquery..

Comment: Then, with the "rawQuery method" you can INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE with the **execSQL** function (this one is not a SQL query, but a SQL command, since you modify the db)

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution, this is better than rawQuery. You don't need concatenate string.
Do not forget the question marks append to string of selection.

```
db.query(Wish_list_Table.TABLE_NAME, null, Wish_list_Table.COL_CATEGORY + "=?",selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
```